# FFTW3 gfortran code is correct only when arraysize is LE 16

Tags: fftw

I have fftw3 code and it works ONLY when array size is less than or equal to 16. Could some expert please tell me what I am doing wrong 
    program fftcalc
      implicit none
      integer n

```
  parameter (n=128)  
  double precision in(n)
  double complex out(1+(n/2))

  integer*8 p, p2
  integer i,j
  real fact


  real f,dt,t,pi
  double precision re


  integer FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_BACKWARD
  parameter (FFTW_FORWARD=-1,FFTW_BACKWARD=1)

  integer FFTW_REAL_TO_COMPLEX,FFTW_COMPLEX_TO_REAL
  parameter (FFTW_REAL_TO_COMPLEX=-1,FFTW_COMPLEX_TO_REAL=1)

  integer FFTW_ESTIMATE,FFTW_MEASURE
  parameter (FFTW_ESTIMATE=0,FFTW_MEASURE=1)

  integer FFTW_OUT_OF_PLACE,FFTW_IN_PLACE,FFTW_USE_WISDOM
  parameter (FFTW_OUT_OF_PLACE=0)
  parameter (FFTW_IN_PLACE=8,FFTW_USE_WISDOM=16)

  integer FFTW_THREADSAFE
  parameter (FFTW_THREADSAFE=128)


  f=25.
  pi=3.14159
  dt=0.004


  do i=1,n
     j=i-1
     t=j*dt

     re=cos(2.*pi*f*t)
     in(i)=re
     write(*,*)  'i,in',i,in(i)

  enddo

  write(*,*) "creating plans"

  call dfftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(p,n,in,out,fftw_measure)
  call dfftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(p2,n,in,out,fftw_measure)

  write(*,*) "execute"

  call dfftw_execute_dft_r2c(p,in,out)

  write(*,*) "forward is executed"

  do i=1,n
     write(*,*)  out(i)
  enddo

  write(*,*)
  write(*,*)"do inverse fft"

  call dfftw_execute_dft_c2r(p2, out,in)

  write(*,*)"inverse fft completed"

  fact=1.0/n
  do i=1,n
     write(*,*)  in(i)*fact
  enddo

  write(*,*)"clean up"
  call dfftw_destroy_plan(p)
  call dfftw_destroy_plan(p2)

end program fftcalc
```

I tried with n=16 and n=10  it works, but when n=64 or so it give mostly zero forward transform.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Note:  when  I added include  file fftw3.f   this file the code worked. Apparently fftw3 needs to have definition of all variables.

Comment: However when I inserted a similar code to a real production job the program is failing to set up fplan which puzzles me. Under which conditions would a plan fail?

Comment: Plan creation is not thread-safe. Does that lead you anywhere?

Comment: Dear Kaveh, I am not familiar with FFTW and I am not using any cores at the moment. So, your comment,unfortunately, does not lead me anywhere. Would you be more specific?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that this is not happening in the context of a multithreaded program, where this code is run concurrently. fftw_plan is not threadsafe and it's use like above would then definitely fail. So your problem from above still persists?

Comment: Actually I think I fixed it. I will know for sure tomorrow.  I think it was a silly mistake when I was putting into production code.  I will eventually have to make it multithreaded as I have to apply it 30 some million times.  Any recommendation?

Comment: PS  I have some experience using openmp. I will use it in opensuse linux environment.

Comment: One last question.  Experimenting with above code after incuding FFTW.f  I got the impression that it works with any even integer. Is that really correct. Should I make sure the length I input to FFT is made of powers of  2 ,3, and 5?